# Are more advanced filters possible on Admin on Rest?

Tags: admin-on-rest

I am struggling to get get anywhere with more advanced filters.

Dates,
As far as I can see `Admin-on-Rest` filter can only be  `"where":"field":"value"...}`. 
It would be great if filter can included a date range. `{"where":"field" between: "value1" and "value2" ...`

like or regexp
Again, `AOR's` filters are exact. Is it possible to use "`like`" or "`regexp`"?

Comment: improve code pieces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL & Loopback REST API backend:

in url:

`filter={"where":{"field":{"regexp":"value"}}`

works perfectly. value "star" will return "starboard", "deathstarzero", etc. No `%` or `*` are needed.

same for "less than" lt and gt
`filter={"where":{"field":{"lt":"value"}}`

in AOR js `filter: { field: {lt:'value'}},`

etc.

Answer (score 1):

The filters values are handled by your backend. Pass them whatever you like.

As you can see in the demo, we might define a "date from" and a "date to" for date ranges: https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest-demo/#/commands